# how to execute js function on load of a js script using JavaScriptExecutor in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to execute a js function after js script gets loaded on an HTML page. But the issue is js script takes some time to load on the HTML page. It works fine if I add a sleep for few seconds in my java code and then execute the js function.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script>
    var loadJS = function(url) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");  
        script.src = url;  
        document.body.appendChild(script); 
    }   
</script>
</html>
```

Java Code

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("www.test-url.com");
js.executeScript("loadData(123)");
```

The above code works if I add `Thread.sleep(5000);` between the above js.executeScript code lines but not when I remove it. How do I replace the
`Thread.sleep(5000);` and still make it work

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this out?

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("console.log('Javascript console');");
```

You need to cast a WebDriver into a JavascriptExecutor object. ExecuteScript functions will not be available unless you perform this cast. Then you will have access to the .executeScript() function

```
Sample driver = new Sample (new SampleProfile());
driver.executeScript("console.log('Javascript console');");
```

Comment: Yes, I have done that and after I load the js using executeScript I want to execute a js function but the function is not found as the script has not been loaded on the HTML page yet

Comment: yeah, I am loading the js in the header

Answer (score 1):

Try out using this code before you execute your javascript, This will force the WebDriver to wait till the page is fully loaded:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
wait.until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd -> ((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
```